# Mongoose aggregation check in twice nested array of objects if specific value exists and return parent id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, multidimensional-array, aggregate

I have an aggregation pipeline in mongoose which fetches posts and along with it the likes and votes (people can vote if the post is a poll) via a lookup. Before returning the queried result I check in the aggregation whether the user (id) has liked the post or not, which I handled with the $in operation under section 02. However, I am facing problems when performing the same check whether a user has voted on a poll or not since I am facing a nested array of objects here. My approach was to have a nested $in operation but this did not work (following 03).

```
return Post.aggregate([
    {"$match": { "issuer.companyId": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(startupId) } },
    {"$sort": { "createdAt": -1 } },
    //02
    {"$lookup":{
            "from":"postlikes",
            "localField":"_id",
            "foreignField":"_id",
            "as":"likes"
        }},
    {"$addFields": { "likes": {"$first": "$likes.likes._id"}, } },
    {"$addFields": { "liked": {"$in": [ new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId), "$likes" ] } } },
    {"$unset": "likes"},
    //03
    {"$lookup":{
            "from":"polls",
            "localField":"_id",
            "foreignField":"_id",
            "as":"polls"
        }},
    {"$addFields": { "polls": {"$first": "$polls.options"}, } },
    //todo: Check if the user id is included in one of the vote arrays and return the selected option id  
])
```

The current output looks as follows:

```
 [
     {
         "_id": "6414698183b285f6f16a17be",
         "poll": [
             {
                 "text": "Facebook",
                 "votes": 0,
                 "_id": "6414698183b285f6f16a17c0"
             },
             {
                 "text": "TikTok",
                 "votes": 2,
                 "_id": "6414698183b285f6f16a17c1"
             }
         ],
         "liked": true,
         "polls": [
             {
                 "_id": "6414698183b285f6f16a17c0", 
                 "voters": []
             },
             {
                 "_id": "6414698183b285f6f16a17c1", //the poll option which should be added in pipeline as new field 
                 "voters": [
                     {
                         "name": “XX”,
                         "timestamp": 1679218784,
                         "_id": "63d3892fd1cc6b5711c67799" //the user
                     }
                 ]
             }
         ]
     },
]
```

Assuming the user (63d3892fd1cc6b5711c67799) voted for the last option (6414698183b285f6f16a17c1) I want to create a new field ($addField) with the id of the poll option selected.

The expected result looks as follows

```
 [
     {
         "_id": "6414698183b285f6f16a17be",
         "poll": [
             {
                 "text": "Facebook",
                 "votes": 0,
                 "_id": "6414698183b285f6f16a17c0"
             },
             {
                 "text": "TikTok",
                 "votes": 2,
                 "_id": "6414698183b285f6f16a17c1"
             }
         ],
         "liked": true,
         "pollVote”: 6414698183b285f6f16a17c1 //This user voted for option TikTok 
     },
]
```

If this not works I will have to handle it in the controller.

Cheers

Comment: Please provide your requested result as a JSON

Comment: @nimrodserok sure. The goal is to store in pollVote the id of the poll option (if the user has voted for any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add one more step with a `$filter`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      poll: 1,
      liked: 1,
      pollVote: {
        $getField: {
          input: {
            $first: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$polls",
                cond: {
                  $in: [
                    userId,
                    "$$this.voters._id"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          field: "_id"
        }
      }
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2HWGMO_m1Ci)